# Show that if $M ≥ 0$ and $|f(z)| ≤ M$ for all $z ∈ ∂V$ , then $|f(z)| ≤ M$ for all $z ∈ V $

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functions, continuity

Suppose that V is a bounded open subset of the plane and $f ∈ C(\overline V)
∩ H(V)$ i.e. $f$ is continuous on $\overline V$ and $f\restriction_V$ is holomorphic on $V.$

Show that if $M ≥ 0$ and $|f(z)| ≤ M$ for all $z ∈ ∂V$ , then $|f(z)| ≤ M$ for all $z ∈ V .$
I am not understanding how to approach this. I tried using Liouville’s Theorem and Cauchy's Estimate.

By Cauchy estimates, for any $R > 0,
|f ′(z_0)|< \frac {M}{R} →0$ as $R →∞$.
I am not going anywhere with this. I do not think this is the right way to show this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: That is (one form of) the “maximum modulus theorem” for holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

As MartinR observed, this is a weak form of the maximum modulus principle (which is usually proved from the open mapping theorem or from the equivalent theorem for harmonic functions)

For domains with a nice enough (e.g. $\mathcal{C}^1$) boundary there is a very easy and straightforward proof of this weak form from Cauchy's estimates:

let $h$ be a generic function which is continuous on $\bar V$ and holomorphic on $V$.
Then By Cauchy's estimates:
$$|h(z)|\le \max_{\partial V}|h| \cdot\frac{\text{length}(\partial V)}{2\pi}$$
This means that there is a constant $1\le K$ such that for all $h$ we have $\max_{\bar V}|h|\le K\max_{\partial V}|h|$. In particular, this works for $f^n$ for every $n$, which implies (since $\max|f^n|=(\max |f|)^n$) that
$$\max_{\bar V} |f|\le K^{\frac1n} \max_{\partial V}|f|$$
Taking $n\to \infty$ we get $K^{\frac1n}\to 1$, obtaining the result.

Note that this strategy clearly fails for general domains (since $\text{length}$ does not make sense). One way of making it work is to use Runge's theorem to approximate $f$ with meromorphic functions but that is killing a fly with a nuke.